# How do I start MySQL service?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to start MYSQL56 Service programmatically from vb2010. I wrote some code to run MySql. but it doesn't working. and show an exception. How do I start that service?
My codes are

```
Dim x As ServiceProcess.ServiceController = New ServiceProcess.ServiceController("MySQL56", My.Computer.Name)

If (x.Status.Equals(ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) Or (x.Status.Equals(ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)) Then
    x.Refresh()
    x.Start()
    x.WaitForStatus(ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
End If
```

The exception is "Cannot open MySQL56 Service on computer 'PERSONAL'"

Comment: Is your program running with the necessary permissions to start the service?

Comment: @Nathan : Thanx. I forgot it. Running from Administrative Priviladge it Works fine. But as a user(without Administrator) how do I activate/start it

Comment: That's a whole 'nother story. Generally services aren't started by ordinary users, by design, so rewriting your question to how to make an exception to that (which you'll need to do) might end up needing to migrate it to [SU].